# Org-roam: cannot resolve UNIQUE constraint failed: nodes.id

Tags: org-roam

I recently started using org-roam, synchronizing my entries folder through the cloud between my laptop and my PC.

Recently, upon startup emacs gives the error

```
Error (use-package): org-roam/:init: EmacSQL had an unhandled condition: "near line 19: UNIQUE constraint failed: nodes.id"
```

I am interpreting this as saying there are two nodes with the same id. However, I only get this error on my laptop, not on my PC even though the .org files used by both are the same.

This is my org-roam setup:

```
(use-package emacsql-sqlite3
    :ensure t)
  
      (setq org-roam-v2-ack t)
  (use-package org-roam
    :ensure t
    :init
    (org-roam-db-autosync-enable)
    :custom
    (org-roam-directory (expand-file-name "brain/" my-org-roam-directory))
    (org-roam-v2-ack t)
    (org-return-follows-link t)
    (org-roam-mode-section-functions
       (list #'org-roam-backlinks-section
         #'org-roam-reflinks-section
         ;; #'org-roam-unlinked-references-section
         ))
    (org-roam-capture-templates
     ;; templates removed here for brevity
     )
       ))
    :bind (
      ("C-r" . nil)
      ("C-r f" . org-roam-node-find)
      ("C-r i" . org-roam-node-insert)
      ("C-r b" . org-roam-buffer-display-dedicated)
      ("C-r g" . org-id-get-create)
      ("C-r a" . org-roam-alias-add)
```

The only difference I am aware of between my laptop and PC versions is the value of my-org-roam-directory.

Org-roam still works as expected on my laptop: the only difference is that it throws out this error upon startup and after saving a file (which interrupts commands like C-x s as is quite annoying therefore).

I have tried rebuilding the cache with (org-roam-db-sync t), which had no effect. Neither has rebuilding after org-roam-db-clear-all.

My question is: does anyone know where this error might originate, and how I could solve it?
If it is possible to silence the error, that would also be acceptable to me, since there seem to be no actual problems in terms of functionality.